# Managing article information

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want you to give me some tips on what I could have done better and is considered "bad practice". The code works, but I think there are better ways to do stuff, so please let me know.

```
var Artikel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'api/items.json',
    defaults: {
        titel: 'Titel niet opgegeven',
        url_titel: 'unieke sleutel urltitel',
        img_path: 'geen image toegevoegd',
        commentaar: 'Commentaar niet opgegeven',
        categorie: 'Categorie niet opgegeven',
        waardering: 0,
        artikel: 'Artikel niet opgegeven'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        if (!this.get('description')) {
            var lazy = 'This user was too lazy too add a description';
            this.set('description', lazy);
        }
    }
});
//Mijn collection wordt voorzien van een sorteerfunctie om niet met 'asc' en 'desc' te moeten werken kan ik gebruik maken van 1 en -1
var Artikels = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Artikel,
    sortAttribute: "categorie",
    sortDirection: 1,
    sortArtikels: function(attr) {
        this.sortAttribute = attr;
        this.sort();
    },
    comparator: function(a, b) {
        var a = a.get(this.sortAttribute),
            b = b.get(this.sortAttribute);
        if (a == b) return 0;
        if (this.sortDirection == 1) {
            return a > b ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return a < b ? 1 : -1;
        }
    },
    url: 'api/items.json'
});
//Eerste view dat wordt weergegeven en geeft een lijst van al de artikels.
var ArtikelLijst = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#app',
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },
    render: function(zoekterm) {
        this.render;
        var that = this;
        artikels.fetch({
            success: function(artikels) {
                if (artikels.sortDirection == -1) {
                    artikels.sortDirection = 1;
                } else {
                    artikels.sortDirection = -1;
                }
                artikels.sortArtikels(zoekterm);
                var template = _.template($('#artikel-overzicht-template').html(), {
                    artikels: artikels.models
                });
                that.$el.html(template);
                return this;
            }
        });
    }
});
//Geeft een detail view van de artikels, in de detailweergave wordt de foto bijvoorbeeld weergegeven als extraatje
var ArtikelDetail = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#app',
    render: function(options) {
        var that = this;
        var artikel = new Artikels();
        url = options.id;
        artikel.fetch({
            success: function(artikel, options) {
                var vindartikel = artikel.where({
                    url_titel: url
                });
                var artikelcol = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                    model: Artikels
                });
                var specifiekArtikel = new artikelcol(vindartikel);
                var template = _.template($('#detail-edit-template').html(), {
                    specifiekArtikel: specifiekArtikel.models
                });
                that.$el.html(template);
            }
        });
    }
});
// de searchview geeft een formulier en zorgt er voor dat de zoekopdracht url-vriendelijk wordt
var ArtikelSearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#app',
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html($("#search-form").html());
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            var querystr = arguments[0].replace(/\+/g, "%20");
            $("#searchQuery").val(decodeURIComponent(querystr));
        }
    },
    events: {
        'submit #searchForm': function(ev) {
            $form = $(ev.currentTarget);
            document.location = '#/search/' + encodeURIComponent($("#searchQuery", $form).val()).replace(/%20/g, '+');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
//De resultsview laat de gevonden resultaten zien
var ArtikelSearchResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#searchResults',
    render: function(query_encoded) {
        var query = decodeURIComponent(query_encoded.replace(/\+/g, "%20"));
        var result_artikels = _.filter(this.model.models, function(artikel_model) {
            var artikel = artikel_model.attributes;
            artikel.waardering = "string";
            for (var key in artikel) {
                if (artikel[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
        var template = $("#search-results").html();
        var result_html = _.template(template, {
            artikels: result_artikels,
            query: query
        });
        this.$el.html(result_html);
    }
});
var artikels = new Artikels();
var artikelLijst = new ArtikelLijst({
    model: Artikels
});
var artikelDetail = new ArtikelDetail();
var artikelSearchView = {};
artikelSearchView.search = new ArtikelSearchView();

function sorteer(sortterm) {
    artikelLijst.render(sortterm);
};
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "detail/:id": "detail",
        "searchform": "searchform",
        "search/:query": "searchResults"
    },
    home: function() {
        artikelLijst.render('titel');
    },
    detail: function(id) {
        artikelDetail.render({
            id: id
        });
    },
    searchform: function() {
        artikelSearchView.search.render();
    },
    searchResults: function(query) {
        artikelSearchView.search.render(query);
        var artikelSearchResultsView = new ArtikelSearchResultsView({
            model: artikels
        });
        artikelSearchResultsView.render(query);
    }
});
var router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Seriously, komaan man, don't put Dutch in your code, it makes us Dutch speaking developers look bad!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see major refactorings in your code. However:

- Use triple-equals (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for more) when doing comparisons with zero or one (and probably the part with `a == b`, unless you know you want otherwise)
- [Pre-compile templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template) rather than doing them on-the-fly for better performance
- You are using Backbone, jQuery, and Underscore (or lodash) - re-examine whether you need all of these libraries. Less code means a faster loading page. (On the other hand, you might need the cross-browser compatibility provided by jQuery - your call.)

  - http://youmightnotneedjquery.com
  - http://vanilla-js.com/